# Command-line tool to convert raw laser scan data to bag file data

Tags: rosbag, laserscan

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to convert raw laser scan data to bag file data, preferably, command-line one. Is there as such? By the way, I have tried to simply change the extension of the file straightaway to ".bag" from ".txt", unfortunately, it does not work.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12035/command-line-tool-to-convert-raw-laser-scan-data-to-bag-file-data/) by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1053 on 2011-11-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-11-22**:
I want to use polar_scan_matcher (http://ros.org/wiki/polar_scan_matcher) that takes an input from a rosbag file. I got the textfile from somebody.

**Comment by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) on 2011-11-22**:
Could you please explain your problem a bit more? Where did you get the .txt file containing laser data? If I'm interpreting this correctly, you want to read from a text file and play that data into a bag file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

At present, I don't believe there is any such utility. The best bet would be to look in the [rosbag](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosbag) API. What is the format of the .txt file?

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2011-11-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-11-23**:
The first 9 fields are fileds like ID, timestamp, roll, pitch, yaw etc and starting 10th field is laser scan value